# Count characters, excluding specific pages

Tags: powershell

thank you for taking the time to read and maybe help me!

I was doing an assignment with counting chars for a document, but now i wanted to see if i could count char without counting the first 3 pages of the document.

Did some research, and couldn't find much about it since i am fairly new to powershell.

```
clear-host 
$b = Read-Host 'Indtast destination mappe' #Beder burgeren om at indtaste destinations mappen

Get-Content -path $b | Measure -Line -Word -Character | Out-File C:\Users\TimHen\Desktop\output.txt #Tæller linjer, ord og tegn i dokumentet.



 #udskriver vokaler og konsonante
```

Comment: You need to define `document` and/or `page`. I guess it could come down to parsing either way.

Comment: @notjustme i got the user to define the document for me, is it possible to do it that way, or do i have to define it from start, and define the pages that i want to count or i want to exclude? :)

Comment: No I meant define it for Stack Overflow. For a Word document there will be actual pages but in a simple txt file not so much (or could be defined in a few ways; number of sheets needed if printed etc). It might come down to parsing text either way and that could be quite a big topic.

Comment: Now i tried to define it a bit better, hope it helps :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Judging from your code, I'd say you're reading a text file.  A text file doesn't have pages, but what you could do is skip the first x amount of lines.

```
Get-Content $b | Select-Object -Skip 160 | Measure -Line -Word -Character | Out-File C:\Users\TimHen\Desktop\output.txt
```

Another possibility (but not really applicable in your scenario) is to use the `Tail` parameter of `Get-Content`.  That will give you the x last lines of the file.

```
Get-Content $b -Tail 3000 | Measure -Line -Word -Character | Out-File C:\Users\TimHen\Desktop\output.txt
```

Comment: Hey Joost! thx alot for the examples, but yeah .txt files doesn't have pages, but if i wanted to do it with a word document .docx, would it be possible? i take the output to a txt file cause it was easier, but wanted to try and get the counting for a docx document :)

Comment: Yes, if you're processing a docx file, you could use properties such as sections or pages.  BUT then you wouldn't simply use Get-Content, but rather COM scripting or other mechanisms to access the file.  This will rapidly become more complex than my example above.  If you Google for "read docx powershell", you'll find ample examples of how to create this COM object and how to manipulate it.